# Is it possible to use EC2 and Lambda for Machine Learning Models

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, aws-lambda

I want to use Amazon Lambda for my Machine Learning Model Web Services but since Lambda has size limits and several of my models are over 1 or 2GB I wondered if there is a way to use S3 to store the models and call them inside Lambda or do I need to use EC2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tho, I'm not very clear on what you're asking for. if you're looking for training modes using lambda, s3. that is very much possible. Refer - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-deep-learning-models-with-aws-lambda-and-tensorflow/.  Other way could be using AWS API Gateway to send requests to your model and use s3 as a store for your models.

Comment: @sulabhchaturvedi no I'm looking for a way to serve my already trained machine learning models as api services. EC2 comes to mind but I wondered if there is a reliable way to do it serverless.

Answer (score 0):

You can side load the app. The lambda can be a small bootstrap script that downloads your app and models from s3 and unzips it. This is a popular pattern in server less frameworks. But you need to remember it will be slow as models and other data will be downloaded to lambda work space. You pay for this during a cold start of the lambda so you will need to keep it warm in a production environment.